# How to get polyline latitude and longitude by click on polyline android?

Tags: google-maps, line, android, select-by-location

I have set Polyline click listener like this :

```
map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
        public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
            int strokeColor = polyline.getColor() ^ 0x0000CC00;
            polyline.setColor(strokeColor);
            Log.e("TAG", "Polyline points @ " + polyline.getPoints());
            Toast.makeText(Draw_Route.this, "Polyline klick: " + polyline.getPoints(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

But i need to get coordinates of that point when user click on polyline, i also used this code to get the codrinates -- >

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng clickCoords) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Found @ " + clickCoords.latitude + " " + clickCoords.longitude);
        }
    });
```

But it only works when i click on map, i need to get that point coordinates on click on polyline so please help me, how to get that.

Answer (score 2):

use `polyline.getPoints();` in your method.

```
map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
        public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
            int strokeColor = polyline.getColor() ^ 0x0000CC00;
            polyline.setColor(strokeColor);
            polyline.getPoints();
            Log.e("TAG", "Polyline points @ " + polyline.getPoints());
            Toast.makeText(Draw_Route.this, "Polyline klick: " + polyline.getPoints(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```